# How is a function with internal optimization called?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, optimization, reference-request

I am looking for references/information about functions like

$$
f(x) = \max_{y} g(x,y)
$$

$x,y \in R$. I don't know if functions like this have a special name? Are there any good references for this type of functions?

Comment: There are uncountably many functions, but only countably many names (being finite strings in a countable alphabet).

Comment: @ProfessorVector And how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: Well, you were asking for a "special name", weren't you? *Any* real function $f$ can be obtained that way, just take $g(x,y)=f(x)$ for all real $y$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector But that is a special case which you assumed without any justification. I am of course interested in the more general case when $g(x,y) \neq f(x)$.

Comment: And the general case should have a more special name than the special case? Hmmm...

Comment: @ProfessorVector Why not? The quadratic function is a special case of the polynomial. Yet, both have their own name. Take a look at the tag, I am searching for references on this type of functions. So a name would help. If you have nothing to add to that question then that is ok. But I still don't see the relevance of your comments to the question.

Comment: @SampleTime In many disciplines (such as optimal control), the function $f$ is called the *value function*. See the Wikipedia article on [the Maximum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem).

Comment: @DavidKraemer Thank you, that looks very promising!

Comment: In optimization this sort of construction appears as a (Lagrange) dual function.